# CAML query Lt operator not giving records as per expected

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I've implemented the custom paging on gird view with the help of CAML query on SPList, I've two buttons for this purpose Next and Previous. The **Next** button is working fine and it gives me the record as per expectation , but when the **Previous** button its gives me 1st page record instead of previous page, for e.g rowlimit is 5 and current page location is 6 then it shows the 5th page record rather than 1st page record. Following is my CAML query :

```
<Where>
 <And>
    <And>
        <Lt>
            <FieldRef Name='ID' />
            <Value Type='Counter'>7</Value>
        </Lt>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='IsActive' />
            <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
        </Eq>
        </And>                                          
        <In>
        <FieldRef Name='Status' />
            <Values>
                <Value Type='Choice'>Open</Value>
<Value Type='Choice'>Under Process</Value>
<Value Type='Choice'>Closed</Value>
            </Values>
        </In>
        </And>  <OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name='ID' />
</OrderBy>
</Where>
```

Any clue or help ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use  SPQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition ?

```
    StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder();
    queryString.AppendFormat(" OrderBy Override=\"TRUE\"> FieldRef Name=\"{0}\"/> /OrderBy>", "Id");
    query.Query = queryString.ToString();

    query.RowLimit = rowLimit;

    SPListItemCollectionPosition pos = new SPListItemCollectionPosition(lastPosition);
    query.ListItemCollectionPosition = pos;

    spListItems = spList.GetItems(query);

    lastPosition = spListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition.PagingInfo;
```

for more info read [How to Implement Pagination in SharePoint 2010 using CAML Query](http://www.tekritisoftware.com/implement-paging-using-caml-query-sharepoint2010)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got my solution which is: to implement the paging onto SharePoint list you should use the **pageinfo** , but one thing you need to keep in your mind is don't use condition on ID like GT/LT/etc because pageinfo is already doing a filter on ID otherwise you'll get unwanted result.

for more click here 
http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/06/22/spquery-pagination/